# I got an error for this code please anyone rectifiy and explain my error

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

The Siruseri Sports Club organizes an annual billiards game where the top two players of Siruseri play against each other. The Manager of Siruseri Sports Club decided to add his own twist to the game by changing the rules for determining the winner. In his version, at the end of each round, the cumulative score for each player is calculated, and the leader and her current lead are found. Once all the rounds are over the player who had the maximum lead at the end of any round in the game is declared the winner.

Consider the following score sheet for a game with 5 rounds:

```
Round   Player 1    Player 2
1       140         82
2       89          134
3       90          110
4       112         106
5       88          90
```

The total scores of both players, the leader, and the lead after each round for this game is given below:

```
Round   Player 1    Player 2    Leader      Lead
1       140         82          Player 1    58
2       229         216         Player 1    13
3       319         326         Player 2    7
4       431         432         Player 2    1
5       519         522         Player 2    3
```

Note that the above table contains the cumulative scores.

The winner of this game is Player 1 as he had the maximum lead (58 at the end of round 1) during the game.

Your task is to help the Manager find the winner and the winning lead. You may assume that the scores will be such that there will always be a single winner. That is, there are no ties.

Input

The first line of the input will contain a single integer N (N ≤ 10000) indicating the number of rounds in the game. Lines 2,3,..., N+1 describe the scores of the two players in the N rounds. Line i+1 contains two integers Si and Ti, the scores of the Player 1 and 2 respectively, in round i. You may assume that 1 ≤ Si ≤ 1000 and 1 ≤ Ti ≤ 1000.

Output

Your output must consist of a single line containing two integers W and L, where W is 1 or 2 and indicates the winner and L is the maximum lead attained by the winner.

Example

Input:

```
5
140 82
89 134
90 110
112 106
88 90
```

Output:

```
1 58
```

```
N = input()
N = int(N)
p1 = []
p2 = []


def lead(p1, p2):
    p1_max = max(p1)
    p2_max = max(p2)

    if p1_max > p2_max:
        return "{} {}".format("1", p1_max)
    else:
        return "{} {}".format("2", p2_max)


for _ in range(N):
    a, b = map(int, input().split())
    if a > b:
        p1.append(a - b)
    elif a < b:
        p2.append(b - a)
print(lead(p1, p2))
```

Comment: You're not adding the score for each round to the previous rounds to calculate the lead.

Comment: You're just getting the winner of each round, not calculating the *cumulative* scores.